# Laravel & PHPUnit : allow process isolation to prevent Mysql Too many connections error

Tags: mysql, phpunit, laravel, laravel-4

Since four months we build a complex web app with Laravel 4 with a good unit test coverage. Now we have 159 tests and 592 assertions to prevent against regression and allow us to easily refactor our app.

Nice picture but since few days we have the following error in the last tests :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections
```

The reason is simple : all tests run in the same process and MySQL allow only a certain number of access in the same time. Now, we have too many tests. If i delete few tests in the middle of my test suite, the last ones pass.

The solution could be to run PHPUnit in process isolation like in the config below but the Laravel tests do not seem to be launched like that. I get an other error in each test :

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Notice: Constant LARAVEL_START already defined in /.../.../autoload.php on line 3
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="true"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>

</phpunit>
```

So my question is : **how could I configure Laravel tests to work with `processIsolation="true"` or do you see an other solution to my problem ?**

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: You can check this discussion : https://plus.google.com/107528973720672293459/posts/bBC5CdKPFQ4 for more informations. Basically, I can't configure Laravel and PHPUnit together to work with processIsolation so I just set max_connections to 1000 in MySQL config. Not very pretty but that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Laravel 4, you can use \DB::disconnect('connection') in your tearDown() function. See doc here: http://laravel.com/docs/database#accessing-connections

"If you need to disconnect from the given database due to exceeding the underyling PDO instance's max_connections limit, use the disconnect method"

Answer (score 4):

You can now do DB::connection()->setPdo(null) to close the connection in your tests's tearDown, tha should solve it. If that doesn't work, you can do `unset($this->app['db'])` in any test extending Laravel's TestCase.

Comment: It could be great but the `setPdo` method only accept an instance of PDO as argument...

Comment: Yeah Taylor edited my PR it seems, I added an alternative to the answer which is the one I'm using currently.

Comment: It works ! I put `unset($this->app['db'])` in my tearDown and that's it.

Comment: This old solution doesn't work with current versions of Laravel (4.2 or 5.0). The solution of @efinal can be used instead, it works great.

Answer (score 4):

As per http://www.neontsunami.com/posts/too-many-connections-using-phpunit-for-testing-laravel-51

This worked well in Laravel 5.1

```
public function tearDown()
{
    $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
        DB::disconnect();
    });

    parent::tearDown();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at Mocks and remove your MySQL dependency: https://github.com/padraic/mockery#mocking-public-static-methods

Going forward, I would actually suggest focusing more on testing your SQL. My firm recently spent a good amount hiring DBAs that really turned our legacy slowness around.

Comment: Thank's for the idea but I really want to test my database for several reasons. I want to test the migrations and I have a lot of functional tests that need a DB access, they are close to integration tests.

An other point is that 90% of the work of a classic web app is to save, access and present datas. If you don't check the DB in the tests, I think that you miss something

Comment: *"If you don't check the DB in the tests, I think that you miss something..."* While that's certainly true, that doesn't mean you have to run unit tests and integration tests at the same time.